# Repeating u-substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, soft-question

A question about the integration technique of u-substitution:

Is it allowed to apply u-substitution over and over again, to reduce the integral to a more manageable form?

Comment: Absolutely. Do you have a particular example in mind?

Comment: Not at the moment, but I recall running into integrals that seem to need a second substitution quite frequently.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is. Example: First substitution $t=x^{1/3}$

$$\begin{equation*}
I=\int \frac{x^{1/2}+3}{2+x^{1/3}}dx=3\int \frac{t^{2}\left(
t^{3/2}+3\right) }{2+t}\,dt.
\end{equation*}$$
You could use the additional substitution $u=t^{1/2}=x^{1/6}$ to obtain
$$
\begin{equation*}
I=6\int \frac{u^{8}+3u^{5}}{u^{2}+2}\, du.
\end{equation*}
$$

Answer (score 3):

**Most certainly.**

However, I do suggest that you do not keep using the letter $u$ for your substitutions to avoid confusion; I typically use $w$ for my second substitution, and $t$ for a third, etc.  Situations in which you need more than $3$ substitutions are fairly rare... (in my experience)

Also, these situations oftentimes arise with applying $u$ substitution, followed by some other technique, then another substitution, etc.  Back-to-back substitutions can be handled by one (bigger) substitution.